# Schedule NSStreams on secondary thread

Tags: ipad, cocoa-touch, networking, nsthread

In an iPad app I'm developing, I need to put the network handling on a separate thread since it occasionally blocks the UI of the app. At the moment, I have created a Connection object in which all the networking logic goes (`NSStreams` and its `delegate` methods).

The main obstacle is how to create the secondary thread and schedule the `NSStreams` on the run loop of this thread. Do I explicitly create an `NSThread` that is then owned by the Connection object?

I have been experimenting with `NSOperation`, but this didn't seem like the best solution as I feel the need for a thread dedicated to handling networking events.

Pointers and advice are welcome. Any sample code might be helpful as well.

Bart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the `detachNewThreadSelector`... approach too, but FYI you can use `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`. It'll throw non-concurrent operations onto separate threads.

To get the streams going, you're looking at this kind of thing:

```
[self.outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:mode];
```

Definitely look at the Apple sample "PictureSharing" at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/PictureSharing.

In particular, copy the `FileSendOperation` and `FileReceiveOperation` classes, and the `QRunLoopOperation`. I also use the `LinkedImageFetcher` sample's `QWatchedOperationQueue` class, which works well with the PictureSharing classes. I took their *SendOperation and *ReceiveOperation classes and turned them into classes sending/receiving what I needed (some NSData).

Then it's as easy as:

```
 FileSendOperation *op;
 op = [[[FileSendOperation alloc] initWithFilePath:somePath outputStream:outStream ] autorelease];

 [self.queue addOperation:op finishedAction:@selector(networkingDone:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

I did just some googling, and I came up with this:

http://kdl.nobugware.com/post/2008/12/22/nsthread-iphone-template/

I think this is what you need ;)

EDIT:
http://www.xprogress.com/post-36-threading-tutorial-using-nsthread-in-iphone-sdk-objective-c/
Maybe that is usefull to...

If you read the code, you see performSelectorOnMainThread (or something) so you can send back info from thread to thread.